Multiprocessing with wrapper function gives strange behavior
I have a pool running several functions, which calls a decorated function which should append to a global list. This works properly until the pool closes, at which point the list that has been growing is empty again, for some reason.
Here is some code to reproduce my issue:
import multiprocessing as mp
import functools

foo = []


def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        foo.append(1)
        print(id(foo), foo)
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def square(n):
    return n * n


pool = mp.Pool()
pool.map(square, [i for i in range(1, 5)])
print(id(foo), foo)

This is a simplified version of what I'm actually doing. What I don't understand is why the list foo is empty after the pool.map. It's globally defined, and so each time square gets called it should have a 1 appended to it. In this code, the first 1 does get appended, but no others. That's not an issue I have in my actual codebase.
Indeed, checking the list inside the wrapping function correctly shows that the 1 has been appended, but outside it's empty again. In my actual code I get the same behavior. There, the list grows properly, however, once I access it again once the pool closes it's empty.

f(*args, **kwargs) Wheres the return? wrapper returns nothing.

There is no return. What f does is not interesting.

Python global objects are not "global" in the sense you seem to think they might be. You can't share such objects across multiple sub-processes like that

Yes, thank you. I thought global also meant "spanning multiple processes".


why the list foo is empty after the pool.map

Mutliprocessing creates processes. Two processes do not share memory, each process has his (copy) of the memory.
foo is private in each process. Because it was not modified in the starting process, it is empty.
Consider researching multiprocessing module documentation, inter-process communication methods, difference between threads and proceses, thread communication methods.

Thanks :) Adding a queue to handle pushing instead fixed my issue.

As it was said before you need to create a shared memory object. Unfortunately each shared object need to know exact memory size in advance (to block this memory for future use). Thus:

it won't be possible to use append method. However you can access each elements by index.
Also you will need to pass created shared memory list and all indexes inside function during pool.map.
And be very cautious to close and unlink shared memory at the end of parallel processing.

See my code for an example of implementation:
Solution 1
Create shared array and control memory yourself:
import multiprocessing as mp
import functools
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import ShareableList


def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # unpach arguments and extract shareable list
        sl, idx, *func_args = args[0]

        res = f(*func_args, **kwargs)
        sl[idx] = res

        # always close access to a shared object at the end
        sl.shm.close() 

    return wrapper

@decorator
def square(n):
    return n * n

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create a sharable memory list
    # you need to provide array size at the creation
    array_size = 5
    sl = ShareableList([-1]*array_size)


    with mp.Pool() as pool:

        # arguments to square function
        args = [i*2 for i in range(1, 5)]

        # pass sharable list inside map function
        _ = pool.map(square, [(sl, idx, args) for idx, args in enumerate(args)])

    # converting memory list ot normal list
    out = list(sl)
    print(out)

    # always close access to a shared object at the end
    sl.shm.close()

    # destroy memory object / free memory
    sl.shm.unlink()

Solution 2
Create shared array through Manager. This solution requires less code, but claimed to be slower vs pervious:
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool
import functools


def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # unpach arguments and extract shareable list
        sl, idx, *func_args = args[0]

        res = f(*func_args, **kwargs)
        sl[idx] = res

    return wrapper

@decorator
def square(n):
    return n * n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:

        n_elements = 50
        
        # create shared list
        sl = manager.list([-1]*n_elements)
        print(sl)

        with Pool() as pool:
            # arguments to square function
            args = [i*2 for i in range(1, n_elements)]

            # pass sharable list inside map function
            _ = pool.map(square, [(sl, idx, args) for idx, args in enumerate(args)])

        # converting shared memory list to normal
        data = list(sl)
        print(data)

